# Recording security events to Active Directory

Tags: c#, active-directory, windows-authentication, audit-trail

I have a WCF service to which I want to add an additional layer of security. For now, just auditing access is all I need.

Our organisation runs Active Directory (Windows Authentication) throughout the company.

I want to log an event whenever a certain WCF service is called, this means I need to know who the caller is, but more importantly, how to I log the event?

I would prefer that the AD/Domain controller keep record of the security incident (and not the local machine/server)

Eventually I want to limit access to services to certain accounts or groups.

Am I making enough sense for someone to steer me in the right direction or at least help me out with the lingo so that I can more easily Google related topics?

Comment: [How to: Audit and Log Security Events in WCF Calling from Windows Forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647243.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: @Reniuz Thank you, these events seem to be written to the local event log, any idea if these entries are propagated to the domain server? I need the audit trail centrally stored in the organisation.

Comment: I am not quite sure what you actually want. Where is your wcf service hosted? If it was on AD server, then you would have everything in same place. If it is hosted on remote server than you can configure to log to file in some kind of share folder of AD server.